# i want to include a pdf to excel converter in my template?

Tags: php, html, export-to-excel, codeigniter-routing

I already have a pdf-to-excel converter in my program files. I want to get it from url. I tried the following:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets\pdftoexcel\PPTECMD.exe">click here to convert</a>
```

but the software is downloaded. I want to open the converter window by clicking the link. How can I do it?
This is the list of pages in my program file (pdf-to-excel):

```
Boxofttoolbox.exe
MMPDF.exe.
jbig2dec.exe. etc..
```

Comment: You're app is hosted locally only?

Comment: But even if it is, you probably can't start exe application from browser without writing special extension for it.